# Is there anyway in C that will automatically detect the data type of the inserted value and then will store the value in that particular data type?

Tags: python, c

If we want to store an integer number we use `%d`, if we want to store decimal number we use %f. So, I am wondering if there is anyway in C that will automatically detect the data type of the inserted value. Consider the following program is written using python:

```
a = 2
b = 3.5
c = a + b
print(c)
```

the output will be 5.5. So it is really great.

The purpose is that i want to write a code that will find out the value of x and y (just two unknown variable)  using cross multiplication method. For a clear concept look at the following equation:

```
(a1*x)+(b1*y)=c1;
(a2*x)+(b2*y)=c2
```

From this type of equation i want to find out the values of x and y.So, first the program will ask the user to input some value for a1, a2, b1, b2 and c1, c2. Then it will perform the operation. That's fine.

Now, If i define the variable type as integer then user will not be able to perform the operation with fraction value. Likewise, if i define the variable type as `float`/`double` the user won't be able to perform the operation with integer number. I mean, the user will not get expected answer.

So, my question is, Is there anything in C, that will automatically detect the data type and then will store it in that particular data type and finally after calculating the result, it will give the result in appropriate form. if the result is integer it will print out integer or if the result is fraction, the output will be decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically? No. That's one of the reasons why people use Python instead of C - it has polymorphism (the ability to perform the same operations on different types), but C doesn't.

In C you would need separate code branches to deal with different types.

Comment: In scientific calculator we can perform this type of operation. So, i wanted to write a code that will not ask user about data type. The user will input the value and the program will calculate the answer. I know i can do this using if else but that's not really what i wanted. Thanks.

Comment: A lot depends on how you represent "values".  You seem to be looking for a polymorphic C datatype, if I understand the requirement correctly (which I still may not). Perhaps if you amend the question to make it clear what the end-product should be you will get more relevant answers. So far you appear to have chosen a specific solution and now seek the tools to implement that solution.

Answer (score 0):

In C you need to decide beforehand what data type you are using.

In this case, I would recommend using `double` and if you need to, have an `if` when printing.

Most major C implementations use [IEEE754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

One of the implications of IEE754 is that if any intermediate step results in a fractional value then [the result will likely not be exact](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Example:

```
double x = 1.0/3;
x *= 3;
x == 1.0;   /* Evaluates to false if IEEE754 is used */
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get a function to print the output like "print" function in python, you still need to decide the datatype of the user input in scanf.

According to the requirement, you can actually declare the data type of the inputs as float/double and print the output with %g.

```
float p = 2, q = 3.5;
printf("%g", p+q);
```

%g will remove the trailing zeros and you will get the require output.